# Swift: Create Dictionary from Inner Items of JSON Array

Tags: json, loops, swift, nsdictionary

In Swift, I have a POST request to a URL which returns JSON similar to this:

```
{"users":[{
"user":{"userID":"1","userName":"John"}},
{"user":{"userID":"2","userName":"Mary"}},
{"user":{"userID":"3","userName":"Steve"}},
]}
```

Here's the Swift code:

```
var result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
println(result?.count)
println(result)
```

...Which outputs this:

```
Optional(1)
Optional({
    users = ({
        user = {
                userID = 1;
                userName = John;
            };
        },
            {
        user = {
                userID = 2;
                userName = Mary;
            };
        },
            {
        user = {
            userID = 3;
            userName = "Steve";
        };
    });
})
```

I'm trying to loop through the "user" elements but nothing I try is working. I have a dictionary of the "user" level JSON, but don't know how to go on to get the child "users" of this. Does anyone know how I can do this? If I could look through them to println() the users' names that would be a great start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as? NSDictionary

if let users = result?.objectForKey("users") as? [[String:AnyObject]]
{
    for user in users
    {
        if let userValues = user["user"] as? [String:AnyObject]
        {
            println(userValues["userID"]!)
            println(userValues["userName"]!)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rakeshbs, that's exactly what I was looking to do! I tried lots of things similar but nothing that got it right. Curious as to whether or not you think my JSON is bloated. Some examples didn't have the inner arrays wrapped in user({}) blocks. Anyway, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: yea. I don't think you needed to use the inner `user` block